# What Does Plum Juice Taste Like?

Tags: die2nite

So, apparently everyone in town received some Christmas gifts in [Die2Nite](http://www.die2nite.com/), including a *Utility Belt*, a *Letter With no Address*, and a vial of *Suspicious Looking Plum Juice*.  Now, I do love Plum Juice dearly, so normally I'd just quaff it in one go, but a few things are stopping me.

- There is a little skull and crossbones in the icon for the Juice - It matches the one in the icon for *Poison*.   Hmmm...
- I was **warned**, as was everyone else involved in the game a few days beforehand with the following: *"Don't drink the Plum Juice!"*

Does anyone know definitively what the Plum Juice does?

---

Here is some information and speculation from a current member of my town:

> Apparently it does absolutely nothing,
>   according to the forums, making it
>   really only useful for cooking meals?
>
> I think, unless it's a joke by the
>   developers, that it has a delayed
>   effect, maybe giving you an infection
>   in a night or two. This way they'd
>   trap the most people into drinking it.

Comment: Off topic, Migrate to Cooking.SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a hero with a kitchen, it can be "cooked" into a delicious meal with 100% success rate. That food can be eaten with no ill effects... so far.

As for eating before cooked, I haven't been in a position where I was OK with dying so I haven't tried it out.

Answer (score 5):

I drank mine and lived a long time.